# How do we know what Cucumber jar files are needed to run Selenium Java in BDD approach?

Tags: java, selenium, jar, cucumber

I learn from some tutorial websites, if we want to integrate Cucumber into our Selenium Java project, we need to download all these jar files and add it into the project :

1. cucumber-core
2. cucumber-java
3. cucumber-junit
4. cucumber-jvm-deps
5. cucumber-reporting
6. gherkin
7. junit
8. mockito-all
9. cobertura

My question, is there any official website that show us what jar files are needed? Just like [Selenium official website](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) has download section to download all needed jar files in one zip package, so we don't miss any important jar.

I checked in [Cucumber official website](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#java), there is no download section.

In this [repository site](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/info/cukes/) , there are so many files available to download and if we don't know which one is needed, then we may get lost. How do we know what jar do we need?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what are all the libraries that you are referencing in your code.

For running basic cucumber test with junit, you need below dependencies

Cucumber-java

junit

Cucumber-junit

Selenium-java

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

below is the official link for reference.
https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm

cucumber-java will load most of the dependencies that you mentioned above no need to write them again.

Below is the internal dependency list of cucumber-java

```
  <parent>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  </parent>

   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>Cucumber-JVM: Java</name>

 <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Let me know if you have any queries